# Passing Image in java

Tags: java

Can someone help me with this Error that I get. When I try to pass in the image it gives me Error. This is part of my project, I completed the rest but have problem with the main screen.

Here is the Error:

```
    Project.java:36: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method drawImage(java.awt.Image)
    location: class java.awt.Graphics
        g.drawImage(img);
         ^
    1 error

     ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
     ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

And this the full Program:

```
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project extends JPanel
    implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    char shape = 'r';
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    Image img;

    boolean start = false;
    boolean help = false;
    boolean Player1 = false;
    boolean Player2 = false;

    public Project() {

        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("mp.jpg");
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setSize(400, 400);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // BG
        Dimension d = getSize();
        g.setColor(getBackground());

        // IMAGE ************************************* ERROR
        g.drawImage(img);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        // Help
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 12));
        if (x >= 900 && x <= 950 && y >= 600 && y <= 650 && start == false) {
            g.drawString("Press START to", 960, 620);
            g.drawString("start the game.", 960, 635);
        }

        if (x >= 900 && x <= 950 && y >= 600 && y <= 650 && start) {
            g.drawString("Choose a Player", 960, 620);
        }

        else {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(900, 600, 50, 50);
            g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 45));
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.drawString("?", 915, 640);
        }
        // Help
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(550, 555, 97, 50);
        g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.setColor(Color.cyan);
        g.drawString("Start", 559, 590);
        // Start
        if (start) {

            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(400, 550, 400, 55);
            g.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 30));
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.drawString("PLayer 1", 425, 585);
            g.drawString("Player 2", 645, 585);
        }

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        shape = e.getKeyChar();
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        if (x >= 800 && x <= 850 && y >= 600 && y <= 650) {
            help = true;
        }
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {// ****** Players Button *******

        // Variables
        Player1 = false;
        Player2 = false;
        // Levels
        if (start) {
            if (x >= 427 && x <= 555 && y >= 564 && y <= 589) {
                Player1 = true;
            }

            if (x >= 648 && x <= 769 && y >= 564 && y <= 587) {
                Player2 = true;

            }
        }

        if (x >= 550 && x <= 650 && y >= 560 && y <= 607) {
            start = true;
        }
        else {
            start = false;
        }

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Project");
        Project dc = new Project();
        f.getContentPane().add(dc);
        f.setSize(1200, 775);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Whoa, apparently I scrolled *way* too soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the API for Graphics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

That class does not contain a method that takes just an image. You probably want something closer to this:

```
g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
```

Where image is the image to be drawn, x and y are the position, and this is the JPanel being drawn in, which is an ImageObserver.

There are other drawImage() methods in the Graphics class that take other parameters as well.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I forgot the basic things.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
```

Numbers are for (x, y) coordinates you'd like to put your image at and keep last as *null* (it's for slow sources like internet).

Comment: What is the benefit of passing null instead of this?

Comment: @Kevin Workman I wouldn't worry about ImageObserver for this application, which obviously is done for learning purposes. In short, to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

drawImage should contain four arguments.

> drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver) // i dont know,  why you are passing one argument to this.

Change this line :

From:

```
g.drawImage(img);
```

To:

```
g.drawImage(img,0,0,null);
```

It works